# Using ScopedTypeVariables to constrain fmap function argument

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've got the following use-case: I'm building a custom AST. As an optimization for certain operations I'm doing on the AST, I've defined a list of children for an AST node thus:

```
data NodeChHolder a = NNode [a] -- For "normal" operators
                    | ACNode (MultiSet a) -- For operators that can be re-ordered and parenthesized arbitrarily
                    | NCNode -- Empty, no children
```

Now, I want to make this type a Functor. However, there's a problem because `MultiSet` requires its type parameter to be `Ord`. So, this didn't work:

```
instance Functor NodeChHolder where
  fmap f (NNode l) = NNode $ map f l
  fmap f (ACNode s) = ACNode $ MultiSet.map f s
  fmap _ NCNode = NCNode
```

I got an error saying that there's "no instance for Ord b arising from a use of MultiSet.map", which is fair.

To resolve this problem, I tried the following approach using the `ScopedTypeVariables` ghc extension. I thought that this would work similarly to how it works with types, but it appears typeclasses are different:

```
instance Functor NodeChHolder where
  fmap f (NNode l) = NNode $ map f l
  fmap (f :: (Ord a, Ord b) => a -> b) (ACNode s) = ACNode $ MultiSet.map f s
  fmap f (ACNode s) = NNode $ map f (MultiSet.toList s)
  fmap _ NCNode = NCNode
```

This also failed with the same error message.
Next, I tried to change it a little, because to my understanding of `forall` from `ScopedTypeVariables`, it should have made sure that the `a` and `b` type variables that I'm using are the same as for `fmap`.

```
instance Functor NodeChHolder where
  fmap f (NNode l) = NNode $ map f l
  fmap (f :: forall a b. (Ord a, Ord b) => a -> b) (ACNode s) = ACNode $ MultiSet.map f s
  fmap f (ACNode s) = NNode $ map f (MultiSet.toList s)
  fmap _ NCNode = NCNode
```

The above didn't work, saying it "couldn't match b with b1", because they are both "rigid type variables". I thought this was because I needed to actually declare type parameters `a` and `b` for `fmap` itself, so I used the `InstanceSigs` extension as well and ended up with

```
instance Functor NodeChHolder where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> NodeChHolder a -> NodeChHolder b
  fmap f (NNode l) = NNode $ map f l
  fmap (f :: forall a b. (Ord a, Ord b) => a -> b) (ACNode s) = ACNode $ MultiSet.map f s
  fmap f (ACNode s) = NNode $ map f (MultiSet.toList s)
  fmap _ NCNode = NCNode
```

But I still got the same error about the rigid type variables.

At this point I don't even know if what I'm trying to do is even possible! Should I give up on trying to make this a functor altogether? With `InstanceSigs`, I could probably do `fmap :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> NodeChHolder a -> NodeChHolder b`, which would fit my usecase, but that would no longer be a true functor...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not do this using the regular `Functor` class. Such class has a method

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

which does not put any constraints on `a` and `b`. This requires any instance to work with any choice for `a` and `b`. Indeed, if instances were allowed to put additional requirements, then `fmap` could not have the type above.

You could however used another type class to represent a constrained functor.
There is one in the package [`constrained-monads`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-monads-0.2.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Constrained.html), which allows the following code.

```
import qualified Control.Monad.Constrained as C

data MultiSet a = Whatever -- stub

multiSet_map :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> MultiSet a -> MultiSet b
multiSet_map = undefined -- stub

data NodeChHolder a = NNode [a]
                    | ACNode (MultiSet a)
                    | NCNode

instance C.Functor NodeChHolder where
  type Suitable NodeChHolder b = Ord b
  fmap f (NNode l) = NNode $ map f l
  fmap f (ACNode s) = ACNode $ multiSet_map f s
  fmap _ NCNode = NCNode
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you lose a *lot* with those definitions of the prelude's type classes. Parametricity, access to functions which use `Functor`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds nice, but maybe at this point using a custom function not corresponding to any typeclass might be a better approach...

Comment: @Mints97 Indeed. That is what e.g. `Data.Set` does: provide a custom `map` function outside of typeclasses